# Python: Creating an unique variable to store information

Tags: python, class, variables

I am doing a program that simulates population growth, but I am not competent enough to understand how to assign a variable to a newly generated person.

Here's my (very much incomplete) code so far:

```
from random import seed
from random import randint
seed()

m = "male"
f = "female"

class Person:
    def __init__(self, gender, age):
        if gender == 0:
            self.gender = m
        else:
            self.gender = f
        self.age = age

def person_Birth():
    x = Person(randint(0,1), 0)
    return x

new_Person = person_Birth() #here's the problem
```

Every time i want to "cause birth" to a new human, how can i store his/her information separately i.e. automatically assign a new variable to store his/her information without explicitly stating a new variable?

I'm sorry if this is confusing to you, I am not sure of the correct terms.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. What are your expected results?

Comment: how about creating a list, and appending new person to the list every time you create one? Then you can reference the person by list index rather than by a specific variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the references to the people in a container structure like a list or a dictionary:

```
people = []
for _ in range(20):
    people.append(person_Birth())
```

Now the `people` list would contain 20 instances of `Person`, which you can either iterate over, or access each one individually with `people[0]` to `people[19]`.

Comment: I totally mis-read the OP question. I don't understand where I came up with my solution. Your solution totally makes sense. +1.

Comment: Thought about something like this, but would have never discovered about it myself. Thanks a lot!